# In Android - How can I set a default style for buttons that are created programmatically?

Tags: android-widget

My Android application can't use XML buttons, because the size and label of the buttons are created based on user input. Therefore I need to create the buttons in the activity and add them to the layout programmatically.

How can I create a default button style (foreground and background color, padding, font, etc), and apply that style to all of my buttons in the Java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this might be the following:

1)  Create a custom button class (wonkyBtn) that extends Button.

2)  In wonkyBtn's constructor, instantiate an Android button, and then reconfigure it to your heart's content...  If it works out that you need multiple flavors of button, you can overload the constructor, or pass in a parameter.

3)  Return a brand, spankin' new wonkyBtn to your application...

I hope I got that right,
R.